# Android: how to use different layout resources for same device inches?

Tags: android, layout, resources, version

I have an app that I developed mainly for 10 inches. However, I need to code it for 7 inches. I have two 7 inches tablets: Samsung P1000 and Samsung Tab 2 P3100. They use different Android Versions - 2.x and 4.0 respectively.
Using a layout from /res/layout-large, fits well for P1000, but gets very small for P3100.

So I thought about create a folder called /res/layout-large-v8, specific for version 2.x and the /res/layout-large would handle the others 7 inches tablet.
But it didn't work. Both tablets used the same /res/layout-large-v8 xmls files.

Any ideas how to make P3100 using /res/layout-large instead of the v8 one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml  For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
```

and Also Refer this beautiful article http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Hey mate, didn't work :/ Both tablets are still getting the same xml file. I've changed a TextView color in each xml file and they both got the same one.

Comment: whats the folder name for layouts in eclipse for 7 inch?

Comment: Actually I need to differ two 7 inches tablets, by version or something else, since dpi are the same. I tried res/layout-large-v8 for API 8 and res/layout-large for the others 7 inches.

Comment: there is no format like res/layout-large-v8 in the document, may i know what is v8? and which one is working among two?

Comment: I wrote the code based on this page: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html but I guess I'll have to set res/layout-large for API 8 and res/layout-large-v14 for API 14 and above.

Comment: It worked! Now, res/layout-large is the default for 7 inches tablet, so as res/layout-large-v14 works for Android 4.0 or above.

Comment: I have a doubt, for this  res/layout-large-v14, how do you know its a tablet or phone for android version 4.0?

Comment: layout-large is usually used for tablets and layout-small for smartphones.

Answer (score 0):

It worked! Now, res/layout-large is the default for 7 inches tablet, so as res/layout-large-v14 works for Android 4.0 or above.